# Поиск в реестре из CMD по шаблону

Tags: cmd

Необходимо в конкретной ветке реестра найти первую из существующих строк и получить ее в переменную. Сделал через

```
FOR /F "delims="  %x in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\..." /f "*"') do...
```

но если находит более одной строки, происходят ненужные действия по циклу, как остановить цикл не нашел (это не BAT фаил и из CMD).

Comment: Необходимо получить любую из установленных Adobe Reader в "reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Reader" /f "*""

Comment: А почему вам понадобилось делать такие вещи из командной строки без батника?

Comment: Возможно, это тот самый случай, когда надо начать изучать powershell.

Comment: _как остановить цикл не нашел_ Гм... что, поставить последней командой в блоке `do` команду `exit` (если из командной строки) или `goto метка_после_for` (если в .bat / .cmd) даже не попробовал?

Answer (score -1):

Помог "exit" после последней операцией с полученной строкой, только не сразу сообразил, что надо между командами добавлять "&&". В результате, запуск ".pdf" файла последней версие Adobe Reader установленной на компе из CMD выглядет так:
FOR /F "delims=" %x in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Reader" /f "*"') do (FOR /F " tokens=3* delims= " %i in ('REG QUERY "%x\Installer" /v Path') do (start "" "%i %jReader\AcroRd32.exe" "c:\123.pdf" && exit))
Тут не все идеально но работает.